# Camera app with modified APK does appear in app list

Tags: android, robotium

I'm currently doing Robotium testing and had to re-sign the camera APK so I can test the camera.

I rooted my phone, grabbed the CameraGoogle.apk & signed it with my own keystore (I used a debug keystore).

I copied the modified apk to my phone.

Now, the Camera does not appear in the app list anymore & when I start my app, it cannot find the camera.

What do you think is the issue? Should I not use a debug keystore?

Comment: How did you copy it?
You should rather install it through adb

Comment: I just did an adb push.

Comment: And you think it should appear on installed apps?
try adb install 'path to apk on computer'

Comment: Glad that you're helping out but snark just undoes whatever good you're doing. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah. I'm having a "file 'GalleryGoogle.apk' does not contain AndroidManifest.xml" error though. I moved the manifest on the root directory but it looks like I need to turn it into binary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29503/discussion-between-maszter-and-dannyroa)